# Pasting hyperlink as text with leading space leads needlessly to broken links

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor

When inserting a link via the SE editor it happens a lot that a broken link is generated.

This seems to happen because a link is selected as text and pasted into the box.

The result is a generated `http://%20https:`

Reason: If the selection contained a leading space, the editor assumes to insert `http://` would be the right thing to do. It is often not. This space is very hard to make out in the box, and the generated link is inserted at the bottom of the editor window, often out of sight.

Since the resulting construct is senseless and uniform, please add a logic that either strips out this leading space in hyperlinks or checks for the presence of `http://%20https:` and deals with it.